# "Оптимальное решение"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Когда-то в школе меня поправили, что нельзя говорить "самое оптимальное решение", но сейчас я это выражение слышу сплошь и рядом. Действительно ли так нельзя говорить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего вас поправили, потому что в лексическом значении этого слова уже содержится сравнительная степень (*оптимальный - наиболее приемлемый, самый благоприятный, наилучший для чего-либо*).  Поэтому сплошь и рядом вы слышите ошибки, от которых вас отучили ещё в детстве.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос спорный. Понятие оптимальности далеко не все трактуют как "единственный самый лучший". В математике, например, существет понятие локального оптимума (обычно говорят конкретно - минимума или максимума). Тогда "самый оптимальный" это глобальный минимум или максимум. Хотя сами матемтики избегают подобной формулировки. Но вполне возможно, что кто-то далекий от математики исповедует схожие взгляды - и запретить ему говорить "самый оптимальный" нельзя.
Короче надо всё время смотреть на контекст. Если в тексте по смыслу ничего не изменится от ликвидации слова "самый", то его и следут опумтить. Но если автор осознано различает "оптимальный" и "самый лучший" (причем так, что это не противоречит локике и здравому смыслу), то почему бы и не быть "самому оптимальному"?